# Can I have two Schengen visas at the same time?

Tags: schengen, italy, norway, schengen-visas

I am a Chinese student in the UK. I just got my Schengen visa from Norway. **They only gave me a single-entry visa**, from 3rd July to 25th July, and **I can only stay in there for 8 days**. I will be in Norway from 3rd July to 10th July, that's fine.

However I need to travel to Italy on 18th July, and back to the UK on 23th July. Can I apply for a new Schengen visa for Italy in a situation like this?

Comment: This is actually not a duplicate of the mentioned question. Here we have the problem, that the second trip is within the validity period of the first visa, while the number of allowed days is exhausted.